# C# List<IEnumerable> get elements in transposed order

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have List which contains IEnumerable objects :

```cs
List<IEnumerable> enumerables = new List<IEnumerable>();
```

There can be any number of IEnumerable objects, but every IEnumerable object have the same size as another objects.
Imagine I have sort of this :

```
[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]
```

I need to get elements from this List in next order as if that matrix is transposed:

```
[10,40,70],[20,50,80],[30,60,90]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: "I need to get elements from this List in next order".  I'm not understanding the desired output.  Can you clarify please?

Comment: If the type and number of elements are the same, why not use an array? Eg `List<int[]>`. Or a 3x3 array?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because we don't know neither type nor size. That's the main problem.

Comment: Do you mean simply to change the rows with columns? In that case, you can use to for inside each other.

Comment: @Zer0 in another words, i need to change the rows with colums.

Comment: Please, clarify the logic of the algorithm, how it should work. Because by given only one example it can be confusing to think of some solution.

Comment: @HamidMayeli yep, i need exactly this. But don't know how as i don't know size and type.

Comment: @ВиталийРуденко even so you can use a `List<List<dynamic>>` or `List<List<object>>`. Working with mixed types on a single "array" will result in problems though, as you'll have to check each object's type before trying to call any method on it

Comment: What do you expect the result to be: `List<IEnumerable<T>>` or `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`?

Comment: @Miraziz I've edited post to clarify that OP is looking for transposing the matrix (with corresponding duplicate)

Comment: @Miraziz i need to group matching positions. Hope thi answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a version of [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) that works on 3 enumerables instead of just 2. It just so happens I wrote an extension method for this some time back:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst,TSecond,TThird,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> items1, IEnumerable<TSecond> items2, IEnumerable<TThird> items3, Func<TFirst,TSecond,TThird,TResult> selector)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> enumerator1 = items1.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSecond> enumerator2 = items2.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TThird> enumerator3 = items3.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator1.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext() && enumerator3.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return selector(enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current, enumerator3.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
enumerables[0].Zip(enumerables[1], enumerables[2], (a, b, c) => new[] { a, b, c }).ToList();
```

Comment: This looks good, but you should add how one should call this extension method to get the desired output (specifically the selector).

Comment: @Zer0 Thanks for the advice. I went ahead and added that.

Comment: Actually this answer do not met OP - count of enumerables can wary.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is pivot the `IEnumerable`s in the `List`. I have a generic version that works with `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` that probably has more overhead than a specific `List<IEnumerable<T>>` would have:

```
// Pivot IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> by grouping matching positions of each sub-IEnumerable<T>
// itemGroups - source data
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Pivot<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> itemGroups) =>
    itemGroups.Select(g => g.Select((item, i) => (item, i)))
              .SelectMany(g => g)
              .GroupBy(ii => ii.i, si => si.item);
```

Here is an extension method that uses explicit enumerators to be more efficient:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Pivot<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> src) {
    var enums = src.Select(ie => ie.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
    var initialMoveNext = Enumerable.Range(0, enums.Count).Select(n => true).ToList();

    for (; ; ) {
        var moveNext = initialMoveNext.ToArray(); // initialize to all true
        var hasMore = false;

        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < enums.Count; ++j1)
            if (moveNext[j1]) {
                moveNext[j1] = enums[j1].MoveNext();
                hasMore = hasMore || moveNext[j1];
            }

        if (!hasMore)
            break;

        IEnumerable<T> subEnum() {
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < enums.Count; ++j1) {
                if (moveNext[j1])
                    yield return enums[j1].Current;
            }
        }

        yield return subEnum();
    }

    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < enums.Count; ++j1)
        enums[j1].Dispose();
}
```